# WebView SSL error?

Tags: java, android, ssl, webview

I have an app with a WebView. I recently changed host, with new host came new SSL that SSL for some reason is not trusted by webview and was wondering how to fix this. Main activity down under here. There is nothing wrong with the SSL because it is working fine in chrome etc. Also if you have a code the "import" of the code would be lovely!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView wb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = wb.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wb.loadUrl("https://www.example.com/");
        wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (wb.canGoBack()) {
            wb.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i would be pleased to have a look @ your domain / certificate. Is it possible ? The certificate must be created on the machine, which runs your web-service.

Comment: [link](https://hukeplan.com) is the domain @louis12356

Comment: So, can you show us the error message ?

Comment: No error just white screen

Comment: check the console of your browser, turn on error messages of your cms.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a day to solve the same problem and finally figured it out why this happened. The main problem of this issue was setting of ssl on the apache server (in my case apache used). To use https (ssl) protocol I put some certificate files(root_bundle.crt, .crt, .key) on the server side and set the paths of the files in the httpd-ssl.conf file. I followed the instruction from the google and most of the guides said about only 2 files but not "bundle.crt" file. I realized that this file is also important.
We should set the path of the certificate chain bundle file in "SSLCertificateChainFile" variable in the httpd-ssl.conf file.

So the settings should be like following.

SSLCertificateFile "D:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.23/conf/key/somedomain_name.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "D:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.23/conf/key/somedomain_name.key"
**SSLCertificateChainFile** "D:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.23/conf/key/root_bundle.crt"

I referenced [this](https://www.sslsupportdesk.com/wamp-server-wampserver-ssl-installation/%22this%20link%22).